# Reading a csv file into pandas dataframe with quotation in some entries

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like

> id,body,category,subcategory,number,smstype,smsflag
>
> 50043,"Dear Customer,Thank you for registering",,,DM-YEBA,inbox,0
>
> 30082,Congrats! Your account has been activated.,,,DM-SBAW,inbox,0

when i'm using `pd.read_csv()` then the whole first observation is included in the `id` column and is not separated among other columns due to the double quotes used for the message body, while in second observation the line is properly separated among the columns.

What should I do such that the first observation is seperated among all columns like in this image
[image]

see what actually pd.read_csv is doing. It's taking the whole observation in id column
[image: vhjn]

when i am opening the csv file in notepad it's adding extra quotation marks to the whole row which is eventually causing the fiasco and the quotation mark already in the file are escaped with another ' " ' as shown below.

> id,body,category,subcategory,number,smstype,smsflag
>
> "50043,""Dear Customer,Thank you for registering"",,,DM-YEBA,inbox,0"
>
> 30082,Congrats! Your account has been activated.,,,DM-SBAW,inbox,0

Comment: When I try to read your data with the `pd.read_csv()` function (pandas version 0.23.4) all data ends up in in the correct columns. Which version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas 0.22.0

Comment: i have updated my pandas to 0.23.4 but still the problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem lies in the way csv file of microsoft excel is actually saved. When the same csv file is opened in notepad it adds extra quotation marks in the lines which have quotes.

1) It adds quote at the starting and ending of the line.

2) It escapes the existing quotes with one more quote.
Hence, when we import our csv file in pandas it takes the whole line as one string and thus it ends up all in the first column.

To tackle this-

> I imported the csv file and corrected the csv by applying regex substitution and saved it as text file. Then i imported this text file as pandas dataframe. Problem Solved.

```
with open('csvdata.csv','r+') as csv_file:
for line in csv_file:
    # removing starting and ending quotes of a line
    pattern1 = re.compile(r'^"|"$',re.MULTILINE)
    line = re.sub(r'^"|"$',"",line)
    # substituting escaped quote with a single quote
    pattern2 = re.compile(r'""')
    line = re.sub(r'""','"',line)

    corrected_csv = open("new_csv.txt",'a')
    corrected_csv.write(line)
    corrected_csv.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to remove double quotes

```
import re
for i in range(0,len(df['body'])):
    df['body'][i] = re.sub('\W+','', df['body'][i])
```

Comment: how would be removing quotes helpful??...once the csv file is incorrectly converted to the dataframe....it will be the same not seperated among the columns.

Comment: that depends on what sort of analysis you want to do on that data.....my answer is only relevant if you want to remove the double quotes(as i understand) ..other wise ignore it..

Answer (score 0):

From your example, your issue seems to be that the opening quote of `Dear customer ...` is not the same as the closing quote (different characters). The issue seems to be in your data, not in `pandas.read_csv`

If you have always the same quote character, you probably are looking for the `quotechar='"'` argument of `read_csv`. More information can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Those are same quote characters...i'm sorry i just typed it wrong...i must have changed the font style by mistake..I have already tried using quotechar=' " ' but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that (by default) a double-quote character is only recognized as representing the start of singular entry if it follows immediately after the delimiter character (i.e. no spaces between the comma and the double-quote). You can solve this issue though by using the input argument `skipinitialspace=True` (i.e. ignore spaces after delimiter). The following code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Create virtual CSV file
csv_file = io.StringIO(
    'id, body, category, subcategory, number, smstype, smsflag\n'
    '50043, "Dear Customer,Thank you for registering",, , DM - YEBA, inbox, 0\n'
    '30082, Congrats! Your account has been activated.,, , DM - SBAW, inbox, 0\n'
)

# Read out CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
```

gives the following result:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
      id                                        body   ...     smstype  smsflag
0  50043     Dear Customer,Thank you for registering   ...       inbox        0
1  30082  Congrats! Your account has been activated.   ...       inbox        0
[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: but look closely at the question, there is no space after the delimeter (,). and still the first observation is not imported correctly after using skipinitialspace